# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel::route()

Tags: php, email, model, laravel-5.3, facade

I am trying to send notification to a particular mail id and is using the following code in my controller:

```
    $product=Product::first();
    Notification::route('mail','suraj@yahoo.com')
   ->notify(new NewProducts($product));
```

But I get an error
 `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel::route()` .
All prerequisites are being added and I even successfully sent a mail when i used an object of my User model. I came across this process in laravel doc5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to find out where the issue is would be:

#### 1. Go to [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/) on Github

#### 2. Type the reported class into search in the top of the page

[image]

It fill [find few results](https://github.com/laravel/framework/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=MailChannel&type=)

Among others, [`MailChannel` class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php)

#### 3. Scan the `MailChannel` class to find the right method

Just looking at class, you'll quickly find [`send()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/bd352a0d2ca93775fce8ef02365b03fc4fb8cbb0/src/Illuminate/Notifications/Channels/MailChannel.php#L48), that does what you want. As suggested by @Suraj

---

All this work can be automated nowadays by using IDE - smart software editor. From my 5+ years experience I recommend [PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), but  you can use any.

**Why?**

It does all 4 steps above right in your browser. **Tells you what methods are available on all classes**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tomáš Votruba for your suggestion.
Later i found out that this was added in 5.5 and it usages  a trait https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Notifications/AnonymousNotifiable.html
which was added in 5.5

Comment: Good job! Thats quite an investigation to just use single method.

Comment: Thanks, @TomášVotruba for your suggestion It was hell lot helpful.